# How do I download an sqlite database from an app on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I made an iPhone app that allows data entry.  Over the past month I have been using it and input a lot of data that is now only on my iPhone in the sqlite database used by the app. I want to get the data off my phone now and store it somewhere else.

Is there anyway to access the sqlite database on the iPhone? If so can this data be updated externally or would the database need to be "re-embedded" and copied back over to the iPhone at build?

Comment: Would just creating a backup in some format you pick then sending it to a server be enough?  You could also fetch an update from a server and process that.  There are various approaches to what you want to do, just trying to narrow down options.

Comment: Not sure how that would work.  How do I get to the sqlite database from the backup?

Comment: I actually found what I was looking for in the Organizer in Xcode.  In this I could pull up the app in my phone and download it to my desktop, then find the database I was looking for, do whatever needed updates and bundle it back in the app and put it back on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a development version, you can download data in Xcode. Plug in your device and find it in the area you do provisioning. Look for your app icon and there's a download button.

Comment: Good to hear it. I forgot to mention that you can upload your stock data to the device from there too. Not too sure how that part works though.

Answer (score 3):

Try the iPhone Backup Extractor.
http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/